# Do cyclic groups always have the shape of a cycle?

Tags: abstract-algebra, geometry

Do cyclic groups always have the shape of a cycle? and as I think that the answer is no, so why this figure is not a cyclic group of order 5 or 10.

> [image]

Comment: every cyclic group is isomorphic to $C_n$ for some $n$, where $C_n$ is the group of all roots of unity of degree $n$.

Comment: What do you mean with "shape" here?

Comment: so why the above figure is not a cyclic group of order 5 or 10? what is the shape of $C_{n}$ ? @ yanko

Comment: @user2520938   the geometric shape?

Comment: This graph is isomorphic to a cycle graph.

Comment: you mean that my answer in the question is wrong? @Chickenmancer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In terms of a Cayley graph, yes.

Let $C_n$ be any cyclic group of order $n.$ Then there is a corresponding Cayley graph who's vertices are labeled by the elements of $C_n,$ and whose directed edges are labeled by a generating set, where if the pair of vertices $(a,b)$ are connected, with edge label $x$, where $x$ is a generator of $C_n,$ then we would say $xa=b.$

This will always produce a cycle graph for cyclic groups. In the case of products, you get a "prism" like structure of the graph, and for semi-direct products, you can see a natural twist in some of the vertices indicating the non-commutativity.

Comment: so every cyclic group can be drawn as a circle? and every circle represent a cyclic group?

Comment: Every cyclic group has a Cayley graph which is a cycle graph. I don't know exactly what you mean by "can be drawn as a circle."

Comment: so what about my second question "why the given figure is not a cyclic group of order 5 or 10 ?"

Comment: I already addressed that. The graph is isomorphic to a cycle, and so you can provide a suitable labeling which will make it the Cayley graph of a cyclic group of order 5.

Comment: but this was a question on a GRE exam and the answer was it is a dihedral group of order 10, I will provide the link just 1 minute.

Comment: That's a different issue. You're asking about the **symmetries** of the star.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2393640/the-group-of-symmetries-of-the-regular-pentagram-is-isomorphic-to-what-math-gr?noredirect=1#comment4941414_2393640

Comment: In that case the symmetries of the star are the same as the symmetries of the pentagon.

Comment: I can not see the difference, could u clarify please?

Comment: A graph is not a group in general. There are constructions which can provide a graph associated to a group. Studying the symmetries of an object will produce a group. This object has bilateral symmetry, and thus it's symmetry group has an element of order 2. A cyclic group of order 5 has no element of order 2, and therefore cannot be the same. However, $D_5$ does have the cyclic group of order 5 as a subgroup and is a semidirect product of cyclic group of order 2 and 5.

Comment: Also, it appears that the Cayley graph was addressed in your other question.

Comment: why a cyclic group of order 5 has no element of order 2? why " $D_5$ does have the cyclic group of order 5 as a subgroup and is a semidirect product of cyclic group of order 2 and 5" from where can I know this piece of knowledge?

Comment: You should study group theory. A good place to start is "Abstract Algebra Theory and Applications" by Judson. It's a free text.

Comment: Thank you soooo much @Chickenmancer  you have a great patience, you are an excellent teacher :)